# How to detect keywords in google sheet files using regex and apps script?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have several spreadsheet files, which I want to check if they have words like **FN.ABCD45E**, if written in regex is

```
FN\\.[0-9A-Z]{7}
```

To detect a single file, I write a script like this:

```
function checkWordRegex() {
  var regex = "FN\\.[0-9A-Z]{7}";

  var check =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('1j_IxQcSwT7L_ecjwHKqxxx1')
                .createTextFinder(regex)
                .useRegularExpression(true)
                .matchCase(true)
                .findAll();

  var status = '';
  if(check.length>0){
    status = true;
  }else{
    status = false
  }
  Logger.log(status);
  
}
```

If i want to check word in multiple spreadsheet files, i must create a loop, like this:

```
function checkWordRegex() {
      var spreadsheetId = [
                               '1j_IxQcSwT7L_ecjwHKqxxx1',
                               '1j_IxQcSwT7L_ecjwHKqxxx2',
                               '1j_IxQcSwT7L_ecjwHKqxxx3'
                          ];

      var regex = "FN\\.[0-9A-Z]{7}";

      for(var i=0; i<spreadsheetId.length; i++){

      var check =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId[i])
                    .createTextFinder(regex)
                    .useRegularExpression(true)
                    .matchCase(true)
                    .findAll();

      var status = '';
      if(check.length>0){
        status = true;
      }else{
        status = false
      }
      Logger.log(status);
      
    }
}
```

But when I search for words using regex for many files, the search process is very long. Maybe my coding is not clean or there are functions that I don't know yet.

Comment: You need to escape the dot with a literal backslash: `var regex = "FN\\.[0-9A-Z]{7}";`

Comment: Sorry for my typo, in the script I've added "\\" to the regex. The problem is that the regex detection process in the google sheet file is quite long. For example, if the files I want to check are 200 files. This will definitely be subject to a quota limit.

Comment: Perhaps you have a script in more clean. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps limit the search to a range or a tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findWords() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet Id');
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  let wA=['the','for','and'];//words to searchfor
  let fA=[];//found array
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      let cwA=c.toString().split(/\s+/);//this could probably be refined
      cwA.forEach(function(w,k){
        let idx=wA.indexOf(w);
        if(idx!=-1) {
          fA.push({word:w,row:i+1,col:j+1,index:k});
        }
      });
    });
  });
  let html='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Word</th><th>Index</th><th>Row</th><th>Col</th></tr>';
  fA.forEach(function(o,i){
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>',o.word,o.index,o.row,o.col);
  });
  html+='</table>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Words');//results display
}
```

Output Dialog:

[image]

You could also use [textFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String))